# How to get phpmyadmin to work with both a reverse proxy and a plain IP:PMA_PORT connection?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, kubernetes, phpmyadmin

I have a kubernetes cluster configured as follows:
**nginx+wp[:5050]** <-- redirect 307 /wp **nginx[:80:443]** /pma rev_proxy --> **nginx+pma[:5000]**

All services share a common external metallb IP. I have a couple of problems with this configuration:

1. nginx+wordpress server is listening on a nonstandard port 5050 configured to use ssl so when I try connecting directly to this server via METALLB_IP:5050 I get an error *'The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port'* which is expected since the browser has no way of knowing that the server is expecting an https request. I attempted to solve this problem by adding this line to my nginx+wordpress configuration:
   `error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;`
   It solved the incorrect protocol problem but introduced a new one: now when trying to access my wordpress administration panel through METALLB_IP:5050/wp-admin I get *'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'* - I assume it's because wp-admin does it's own redirection which causes an infinite loop. I tried adding `define( 'REDIRECTION_DISABLE', true );` to my wp-config.php but the error persisted. Note: only one port [:5050] is allowed to be open for this service!
2. I've setup a reverse proxy to phpmyadmin with the following block:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
    proxy_pass https://phpmyadmin-service:5000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

But after I input my name and password and click 'Go' my uri is changed to `https://METALLB_IP/index.php` and I get a *'404 Not Found'* since my nginx+phpmyadmin server listens on port 5000 not 80/443! I should also mention that this error occurs only when trying to connect through a reverse proxy, if I specify METALLB_IP:5000 to connect, everything works fine.

Any advice or links to the relevant parts of the documentation would be greatly appreciated!

**edit:** I now have a half working solution for phpmyadmin reverse proxy: if I add `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = '/phpmyadmin';` to my config.inc.php, METALLB_IP/phpmyadmin login/logout starts working! But the downside of this solution is that now a login with direct connect through METALLB_IP:5000 gives this error: *'Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.'* This issue might be related to [#16496](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16496)
My current phpmyadmin 5.0.4 configuration:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "mysql-service";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = "3306";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = "mysql";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = "mysql";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = '/phpmyadmin';
```

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress, you need to add the following item in WordPress config:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com`);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
```

This will let WordPress know what is the URL you use in the browser to access the site. Replace `example.com` with your domain name.

For PHPMyAdmin, try removing everything else than `proxy_pass` in your configuration. At least I have PHPMyAdmin working this way in a reverse proxy situation.

Comment: Removing everything except `proxy_pass` didn't make any difference and I already have my WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL set in wp-config.php :(